# emacs - shortcuts for horizontal and vertical split

Tags: emacs

I am switching to emacs from vim and in my .vimrc, I have the following shortcuts for horizontally and vertically splitting the screen:

```
" Create window splits easier. The default
" way is Ctrl-w,v and Ctrl-w,s. I remap
" this to vv and ss
nnoremap <silent> vv <C-w>v
nnoremap <silent> ss <C-w>s
```

How could I do this in emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Emacs -- I see from a couple of prior questions that you're using `evil`, the Vim emulation layer.  Here's the short version:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "vv" 'split-window-horizontally)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "ss" 'split-window-vertically)
```

Have a look at the [EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) on `evil`, as well as the (sadly outdated) [Evil manual](https://bytebucket.org/lyro/evil/raw/277db511bff206942a4870ba918878f1ed591d3f/doc/evil.pdf).

I'd also suggest browsing through the `evil` source code to get a sense of how to do things like binding keys by using the `find-library` function.  `M-x find-library RET evil` and `M-x find-library RET evil-maps` should get you started.

Comment: The question does not reference `evil` mode. The answer is a bit 'Fortran in any language.'

Comment: The OP had recently asked a question about installing `evil` (subsequently deleted?).  He's also coming from Vim and is asking how to replicate a key remapping in normal mode.  Hence, the answer of how to use `evil` to replicate what he has in Vim.

Comment: That being the case, does not alter the future. Many Many people will hit the question from a search results page - many without 'Vim' in the search terms. dagda1 getting an answer is just a fortunate side effect of the StackOverflow process. The big effect is statically addressed 'answers on the internet' not 'I got an answer'. That's why poor questions get downvoted and duplicates get closed.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using evil mode and I searched "splits evil mode" and got this, so it was useful for me.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're planning to use some vim-emulation mode for Emacs, such as [`evil-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil), you might be interested in the standard way of doing window splits:

- <kbd>C-x 2</kbd> -- `split-window-below` (vertical split)
- <kbd>C-x 3</kbd> -- `split-window-right` (horizontal split)
- <kbd>C-x 0</kbd> -- `delete-window` (deletes the current window)
- <kbd>C-x 1</kbd> -- `delete-other-windows` (makes the current window fill the frame)

Comment: I don't know why but for me `C-x 3` is vertical split (one window becomes two windows side-by-side). Is it simply a terminology issue?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am using "horizontal split" in the sense that the resulting windows are aligned "along the horizon" so to speak, that is, left and right of each other.